# Is it possible to check a value in every child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Hello please i have a question is it possible to check value in every child of firebase real time database ? For example i have 5 children and in everyone i have value "start time" and i need compare this values.
Because i want create booking system.

My database setup:

[image: image of how my database is setup]

Comment: Can you share database structure?

Comment: Show us your database structure and what have you tried so far.

Comment: i added picture of my database where i need compare student name as number in all children of database

Comment: and i want ask else can i rank children in firebase by studen name ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is always good to share some of the code showing your attempt at solving the problem

Comment: Yes you can RANK and order CHILD NODES by STUDENTNAME using `orderByValue()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase query to check for specific values. Check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use    `OrderByValue()` for querying the data that you want to fetch and check value.

Comment: but can i use this when every value is in different child ?